# Swift datefomatter returns wrong time

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I am working in iOS app with `Dateformatter` which is return wrong time. I don't have any idea to fix this. Can anyone please correct me to get correct time?

```
let dateString = "2020-08-11T05:32:33.000Z"

func approach1(){
    
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX"
          
    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) else {fatalError()}
    
    printTime(date: date)
}

func approach2(){
    
    let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.formatOptions = [.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]
    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) else { fatalError()}
      
    printTime(date: date)
}

func printTime(date: Date){
    
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    dateFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
    dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
    let time  = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    print("date: \(date)")
    print("Time: \(time)") // Here it's always wrong time with those approach.
}
```

**Current Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong. The date formatter returns the correct time

The date string

> "2020-08-11T05:32:33.000Z"

represents a date in UTC(+0000).

Your local time zone is obviously UTC+0530. `DateFormatter` considers the local time zone by default.

To format the `time` also in UTC you have to set the time zone of the date formatter explicitly

```
func printTime(date: Date) {
    
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    dateFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
    dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
    let time  = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    print("date: \(date)")
    print("Time: \(time)")
}
```

Comment: Oh, Thanks for the explanation. I got it.

Comment: Don't forget to set the date formatter locale to "en_US_POSIX" before setting the dateFormat

Answer (score 2):

By default dateFormatter  works with local time zone. To have correct display set its time zone to UTC : dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the time zone when formatting to string (by default it's using your current local time zone):

```
func printTime(date: Date) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC") // <- add here
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    dateFormatter.amSymbol = "AM"
    dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
    let time = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

    print("date: \(date)")
    print("Time: \(time)")
}
```